# Network issues - resolvconf problem

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, resolv.conf, resolvconf

Internet access is available for a brief second when the browser is initiated, but after a split second, internet connection is unavailable.

Searching a bit in the forum, I found out that

`dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` and `service network-manager restart`

resolved the problem temporaly, needed to be done after every boot.

This happended after running xflock4 with the shortcut `CTRL+ALT+L`. The screen went black for a minute, then became red. 
Without response, I powered-off the machine manually.
Is there a permanent fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You shouldn't manually update your resolv.conf, because all changes will be overwritten by data that your local DHCP server provides. If you want it to be static, run sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf and answer "no" to dynamic updates. If you want to add new entries there, edit /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base and run sudo resolvconf -u, it will append your entries and DHCP server's entries.

2) Try to edit your /etc/network/interfaces and add your entries there, like

auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet dhcp 
dns-search google.com 
dns-nameservers dnsserverip 
and then restart /etc/init.d/networking restart or sudo ifdown -a and sudo ifup -a

3) Your system uses udhcp which is a very small DHCP client program. The udhcp client negotiates a lease with the DHCP server and notifies a set of scripts when a leases is obtained or lost. You can read about it's usage here or just edit this script (as you did).

Comment: This was a bigger hassle then I expected. I ended up reinstalling the system in the end. Thank you for your kind response, Mayur, but I couldn't fix it, sadly.

Comment: but sometimes we have a large backup then reinstallation is the big challenge.